# Example of using XML functions in MySQL. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, function

Can someone please provide an example of how to store, and read xml data into MySQL? 
I'm using php, and I've read this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xml-functions.html

But I simply cannot get results that I want.

Thank you very much. (I'm using this because I have a lot of calls to the data stored in the xml, and I need faster functions.)

[EDIT]
As per request:

I currently have 30k .xml files with anywhere from 25-50 elements in each file. 
I ask for values in various files hundreds of times a second. 
I'm finding there's a huge bottleneck from the I/O actions preformed here.

I think storing the data from the .xml files into a database would make accessing the values
a much faster process.

I'm asking for help/advice on how to go about this.

Comment: Just my 2 cents here, but unless you have a very unique need you should not be storing XML documents in a database. Hopefully your plan is to shred incoming documents into a relational structure and then generate XML on the fly from the DB when you have an outbound request.

Comment: The issue with that is this: 

I call on the data in the .xml files a lot.  I/O calls are timely. 
So I should store the .xml files into a database. 

I have 30k .xml files with anywhwere from 25-50 elements each.  I think writing a lot of sql statements is the wrong way to send the xml data into the database.  

My only other solution was to store serialized xml files into a blob, deserialize, the DOM parser.  But that's expensive too.

Comment: You might want to [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11033605/edit) with more concrete data about what you are trying to do and where you are stuck. Asking people to provide a general tutorial is out of scope.

Comment: You'll still have I/O calls with a database... DBs aren't typically stored in memory.

Comment: Having stored a lot of XML files in a database myself, it won't give you faster access to the data in the XML (I used it as I needed to be able to get the right XML, the data for which was also in the SQL). So why don't you put the data you need from the XML in the database?

Comment: Edited my original question, hope this clears up my problem.

Comment: You can also store those XMLs in ramdisk, thus improving I/O performance...

Comment: Woody, though I could do that, i felt that was a really bad way to do it.  My SQL queries would be HUGE.  Of course, I'm getting at like: 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO gamelist VALUES ('".addslashes($value->name)."',$value->id,'".$value->image->super_url."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE game_id='$value->id',name='".addslashes($value->name)."',image='".$value->image->super_url."'") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the data stored in the database will be no faster than accessing them on the disk. The database speed is provided by being able to index the data, and the contents of the XML is (I assume) not indexed.

So unless you can take key fields out of the XML it is not going to help you.

However, in answer to your actual question (rather than whether it is a good idea), if you are using a mysqli connection and a prepared statement:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO MY_DATA_TABLE (Id, Data) VALUES(?,?)")) 
{   
    $stmt->bind_param('ib', $id, $data);
    for($i = 0; $i < $numfiles; $i++)
    {
        $id= $row;
        $data=  readfile($id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
 }
```

Something like that? (Haven't tried it).

EDIT:

But from your answer, if you just want to read the elements from the XML files, you probably need to look at simple XML: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I'm looking up mysqli, because I have no idea what it is, or what this code is doing. 

I think I'm just looking for a lazy way to extract all the elements from an .xml file and store them into a database.

Comment: OK, your question seemed to say you wanted to store the XML files within a database (which I said wasn't a great idea in the first part of the question). If you want to store the elements of the XML files in the database, that is a different question, and probably depends on the type of data in your XML file. This code is reading a load of files and storing their contents in a blob in the database

Comment: Oh, yeah I don't think that's what I'm looking for.  Though this mysqli seems to point more towards what I want.  And sorry for the misdirection.  

I'd love to ask how I can go about storing the elments of an xml file into the database.  

And as for what type of data in my xml file, I'm not really sure how to answer that.  

Ints, varchars?  I don't understand the question fully.

Thanks.

Comment: See my edit. What I mean is the structure of your data. Does everyone of these 30,000 files have a element called 'name' that you have to search through, what is it you are looking for when you search them. What do they have in common. If they have common tags, you can strip those out (like 'name') and put them in a field in the database, so then you can do a proper SQL search on the data for a name, rather than opening every file. In the files I did it with, they were manual pages, so each page had an ID, a catagory, a group, etc, so you could find the one you needed

Comment: Woody, each of the files are all similar-esk data.  They do all have an element called 'name'.  But there are some moments where there may be 'screenshots' and each file may have a different amount.  

Here is an example file, I feel like it'd be a lot of work to write the code to parse each file, and store each element into the database manually.  

I only assume there was an easier way.  

http://filebin.ca/5GuXAnXHFUe/7481.xml

Comment: OK, that data was obviously generated from a database, which I am guessing you don't have access too, but it refers to IDs of people / plots etc. I would scan all the files, capture those IDs and put them in a table with the ID of the XML file. If you match, then you would only have a few sections to test